# jQuery - hasClass issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has these buttons in footer

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning redirect store-submit">Add and redirect</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success store-submit">Just add</button>
```

Although form is not submitted by these. They are used to trigger jQuery event

```
$("button").click(function(e){
 if($(this).hasClass('store-submit')){  
   e.preventDefault();
   var form_action = $("#add-modal").find("form").attr("action");
   var data = $("#add-modal").find("textarea[name='data']").val();
   var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
   var type = {{$user->type}};
   $.ajax({
       dataType: 'json',
       type:'POST',
       url: form_action,
       data:{data:data, _token:token}
   }).done(function(data){
       $("#add-modal").modal('hide');
       update(data.id); //calling out another function
        if($(this).hasClass('redirect')){      //DOESNT WORK
            //some action
         }
   }).error(function(data){
     //error
    });
}
});
```

The weird thing is that first class-check is working. Altough whatever button i click it never triggers part when class "redirect" is checked. I am kinda struggling to resolve this issue and i have no idea what could've I possibly did wrong. Any help would be greately appreciated.

Have a nice day.

Comment: callback function inside `$.fn.ajax` method has different context than you are expecting. You should set option `context: this` of ajax method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$(this)` is not pointing to the button anymore. In order to fix this, you can use `.bind()` as suggested by @dfsq or you can assign the `$(this)` to a variable and then use it. Like

```
var btn = $(this);
```

And later use the above as

```
.done(function(data) {
  $("#add-modal").modal('hide');
  update(data.id);
  if(btn.hasClass('redirect')) {
    //some action
  }
```

Also, the good part over here is that you don't have to call `$(this)` everywhere, as you are holding a reference of `$(this)` in a variable. So you can also change

```
if($(this).hasClass('store-submit')) {
```

TO

```
if(btn.hasClass('store-submit')) { 

//and practically everywhere you can use btn instead of $(this)
```

Comment: Okay that seems easy enough. Great answer. Will accept this as soon as possible :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind callback function to correct context. One way to do it is using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
.done(function(data) {
   $("#add-modal").modal('hide');
   update(data.id); // calling out another function
   if ($(this).hasClass('redirect')) {
      //some action
   }
 }.bind(this)) // note: bind(this) call
```

Comment: jQuery `ajax` method has an option for that :)

Comment: @A.WolffI know, also jQuery has `$.proxy`, also one could save var self = this. Accepted answer is optimal I think.